# AS3 - Button inside MovieClip triggers MC's event

Tags: actionscript-3, button, mouseevent, movieclip

On stage, I have a MovieClip named "mc" with a simple rectangle drawn inside. mc also has a Button child named "btn" which is another simple rectangle ( smaller than mc's rectangle obviously). Then I have this code on stage.

```
function mcDown( _e:MouseEvent):void{
    trace( "mc" );
}
function btnClick( _e:MouseEvent):void{
    trace( "btn" );
}
mc.addEventListener( MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mcDown );
mc.btn.addEventListener( MouseEvent.CLICK, btnClick );
```

The problem I am having is when click the button, mcDown event is also triggered and traces both "mc" and "btn".

How can I make it so that when I click the button, it triggers only btnClick and not mcDown along? I tried MOUSE_UP instead of CLICK, same problem. And mcDown event has to remain MOUSE_DOWN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to prevent bubbling except setting the bubbles parameter as false in the dispatchEvent.

```
dispatchEvent(EVENT_TYPE, BUBBLES,....);
```

However, you can avoid the bubbling by doing a check. Just have the below line as first line of your listener function it avoids the events dispatched from all objects other then targets.

```
if(e.eventPhase != EventPhase.AT_TARGET) return;
```

So, for your sample code, when you click on the button both the events dispatches but in the **mcDown** function it won't execute after the above said line.

Answer (score 0):

If you add button in a MC, and you click on the button, you also click on the MC, because the part of the MC that is under the button is still there and it runes the function for the whole of the MC, you can't remove it.

So it's good idea to make a function that will check if the button is pressed, otherwise it will run the function for the whole of the MC.

This one should do it.

```
//add this in you constructor

mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, myReleaseFunc);
function myReleaseFunc(e:MouseEvent):void {
    if(e.currentTarget.name == Btn1) //Btn1 is instance name for a button
    {
         Btn_func1();
    }
    else if(e.currentTarget.name == Btn2) //Btn2 is another button.
    {
         Btn_func2();
         //For every button you'll need to add another function and if statement to check if that button was clicked.
    }
    else
    {
         Mc_func();
    }

} 

// this outside the main class

function Mc_func():void{
    //you code here
}
function Btn_func1():void{
    //you code here
}
function Btn_func2():void{
    //you code here
}
```

I think that this way is much more effiecient and it will works better and faster and you'll have a lot smaller chance of overloading the system.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, at least now I know that it is not possible the way I hoped. Unfortunately though, I can't use your method because the "mc" will be nameless in actual project and it will have more child buttons and various type of interactive content. Guess I'll have to stick to my first plan. I create an invisible 1x1 button in "mc" below everything and add the mcDown event to that instead. Then I set its scaleX and scaleY properties to whatever width and height the "mc" has. I was hoping maybe I could achieve this without that extra button but seems the easiest way was that.

Comment: I can't see why it wouldn't work. If 'mc' has a name will not change anything so it'll be good to give it an instance name. Also this code can be used by infinitly number of objects. You just need to add few lines per object. See up for the update.

Comment: I tried to simplify the problem at hand. In actual project "mc" clip instances are created as empty clips first and added dynamically, can be more than one. And the children can be so many different things, it's just not possible to add them all, would be too many extra lines. Maybe if "mc" clip is in Library and has a Linkage Class, instead of a name that class can be used by getQualifiedClassName() or something like that. If class name is different than mc's use return to abort.