# Action Script 3 root issue. Trying to call function from a listener inside a MoiveClip

Tags: actionscript-3

See pics attached: I have a button(expnd_btn) inside a movieClip(bannerContent), and trying to add a listener to it so it can call code on the main timeline frame2. frame1 has no clips.

```
bannerContent.expnd_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,ShowPanel);
```

It doesn't work inside the MC... but code works if I remove the button and place it on the main stage and ref like below.

```
expnd_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,ShowPanel);
```

Code entirely(main stage):

```
bannerContent.expnd_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,ShowPanel);
function ShowPanel(event:MouseEvent){
//do something
}
```

I dont get an error indicating the listener cant attach to the btn inside the MC... however the btn isnt finding the function outside.

**So question:**
 1. How do you write this differently so it is somewhat FORCED to work. I tried below but it gives errors

```
function get Expndbtn():MovieClip{return this.getChildByName("expnd_btn") as MovieClip;}
bannerContent.Expndbtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,ClosePanel);
```

3. Also how do you write _root.callFuction() or say _global.callFunction() in as3.

[image: code in banner]
[image: keyframing structure]

Comment: I think it has been answered in a different question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12338320/as3-button-inside-movieclip-triggers-mcs-event.

Comment: dont see it as the same. I saw this one already. Cheers.

Comment: What do you mean by "It doesn't work"?  What error message do you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I will advise you to read a bit more about Action Script and how it works.

On each frame, you attach code specific to the **particular frame** and *maybe* the frames after that. When talking about nested MovieClips - they have a tree structure. So if you write code in some frame, your code works in that particular MovieClip. `this` is the current clip. So `this.parent` is the parent, and `this.expnd_btn` will get `expnd_btn` from the current clip..

My point is - write the code where you want, but keep in mind the so called `scope` - where are you are the moment. If you write code in root - insert the whole path to the button: `bannerContent.expnd_btn.addEventListener..`; If you write code **inside** the banner, then you only need `expnd_btn.add..`, **but** the function that is called on click is **NOT** here, so you need to write the path to it: `expnd_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, this.parent.ShowPanel);`

Note: `this` is not needed, but is sometimes helpful to understand what's going on. Simply `btn` means `this.btn`. Good luck!

Oh, one more thing - when you want to call a function which is on the next frame, think of this real world example: You live in the present (current frame). You know how to bike and can do it (call a method). Tomorrow (next frame) you will learn how to swim (method is defined on second frame, but you are still at frame 1). So you want to swim today? :)

There is a reason why it's called `timeline` - it's because it happens with time. If you want to call something - you can call methods only from the past (previous frames). Either define everything on first frame, or learn how to manage those needs (or best - start using classes).

Comment: Thanks for taking the time with a detailed answer. Cheers bud.